# How do I prevent the user from moving a UITableViewCell to a specific location?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my TableView, the bottom cell has an "Add Cell" button that is used to..well, add cells. However, the app crashes if the user reorders the tableivew by moving a normal  informational cell to the last position, making the "Add Cell": cell next to last.

I was able to prevent moving the "Add Cell" cell using tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:. I need something like tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath, but I only want to stop movement if they try to move it to the last position. Ideally, I'd need a hypothetical message like tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this by implementing [`tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW9) in your table view's delegate.  Make the method return an index path that has a lower row number than your “Add Cell” row.